# Trouble including a Matlab surf plot (pdf or png) with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, external-files, matlab

I have successfully used `\addplot graphics` before. Now I have a surf plot in Matlab, which I exported as png and pdf and I would like to include the image with `\addplot3 graphics`.
I found some questions on the topic [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78855/problem-with-external-graphics-and-3d-pgfplots?rq=1), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/why-do-i-fail-to-import-external-3d-plots-with-pgfplots), all of which did not help me. I tried several times to get a correct set of points from `pgfplotscsconversion`, but either my figure looks something like in [the first link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78855/problem-with-external-graphics-and-3d-pgfplots?rq=1) or the size is simply srewed up - no matter which format I use. I followed the conversion instructions in [the second link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots), which was supposed to give the correct figure size, but it seems the axis box is simply too small (or the image too large). This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[3d box,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=1,zmax=3]
\addplot3
graphics [
points={
  (0.42545,0.84598,3) => (165.418,269.808)
  (0.62718,0.73739,3) => (221.628,273.02)
  (0.36528,0.67204,1.8154) => (179.872,164.615)
  (0.81564,0.23471,1) => (334.851,96.36)
}]
{../matlabout.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Without the min/max values, it looks even worse. I fear it is related to [the third post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/why-do-i-fail-to-import-external-3d-plots-with-pgfplots), but I'm hoping that there is a solution without fiddling around manually...

Edit: Here is an image: [image: surfplot]

Comment: Could you provide the image (or one like it, if it contains sensitive information)?

Comment: By trial and error I found that `xmin=0.5,xmax=1.7,ymin=0.3,ymax=1.4,zmin=1,zmax=3` makes the whole thing fit. But those are not the correct x and y values!

Comment: My first question is whether you used any 3rd party packages to create it in matlab? The reason for my asking is because otherwise `matlab2tikz` is your answer.

Comment: It seems as if the resulting projection is correct, only the limits are sub-optimal, right? Pgfplots takes the bounding box from the `points` key to determine the limits. Could you add `debug=visual` right in front of `points` (perhaps combined with `\begin{axis}[clip=false]`)? This should visualize how the `points` argument fits to the graphics. With the screenshot above, I could not map it to the image; but perhaps tex.sx has resized the graphic.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)? That's always been my best bet for these things.
You create your plot in matlab as normal and then, having downloaded the package `matlab2tikz` to your current working directory type >>matlab2tikz('filename.tex') and a file is created written in `tikz` commands.

Example
[image]

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.3.2.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2013, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
%
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
%
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.378125in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5, xmax=2.5,
xtick={\empty},
ymin=-0.872306147353593, ymax=16.8315076281438,
ylabel={Normalised cfu (Y) values}
]
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table{
1 1.12905875646794
1 2.78718445646597
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table{
2 1.36133715554353
2 3.39777143317797
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table{
1 0
1 0
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
forget plot
]
table{
2 0
2 0
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
0.925 2.78718445646597
1.075 2.78718445646597
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
1.925 3.39777143317797
2.075 3.39777143317797
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
0.925 0
1.075 0
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
1.925 0
2.075 0
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
0.85 0
0.85 1.12905875646794
1.15 1.12905875646794
1.15 0
0.85 0
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
1.85 0
1.85 1.36133715554353
2.15 1.36133715554353
2.15 0
1.85 0
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
0.85 0
1.15 0
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table{
1.85 0
2.15 0
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=+,
mark options={solid,draw=red},
forget plot
]
table{
1 2.86116610278157
1 2.95124846970011
1 2.96462408742799
1 2.97672923606257
1 2.97796965154811
1 2.99660242862322
1 3.0037675940822
1 3.01411361097206
1 3.02378221975569
1 3.03465537879915
1 3.05104691875102
1 3.0524887902421
1 3.054698367375
1 3.06946423244171
1 3.123401396294
1 3.18701681450716
1 3.22331347185298
1 3.26431457826656
1 3.26575600527331
1 3.28891193278492
1 3.29126780809468
1 3.29994977231928
1 3.30151454616189
1 3.51369680474291
1 3.55594005913051
1 3.580267849604
1 3.62139284445829
1 3.63331706393713
1 3.69712860434564
1 3.71789360239462
1 3.73137135176868
1 3.73793814785515
1 3.74613321323258
1 3.74713290237321
1 3.75915881837724
1 3.77368294360208
1 3.78414412300685
1 3.84867955908334
1 3.90365624369993
1 3.90753006730174
1 3.91592893219147
1 3.97164083228678
1 3.98212699077419
1 3.99994581987529
1 3.99996287392214
1 4.00373730182012
1 4.02157837509262
1 4.02822619449464
1 4.05222199937739
1 4.18447335976829
1 4.18677023062065
1 4.29946448151493
1 4.31505394260622
1 4.32393762989871
1 4.34436165598829
1 4.35944927796665
1 4.39399815332052
1 4.46042061381864
1 4.46382363320185
1 4.49589099528811
1 4.52114499865807
1 4.52742866833533
1 4.59350844545217
1 4.59496487831338
1 4.61146788071285
1 4.63334374533791
1 4.78194759348968
1 4.83985818575815
1 4.85513436268938
1 4.92123603955527
1 4.93285176189552
1 5.05004769917023
1 5.16969391058426
1 5.22313998874544
1 5.29553454518465
1 5.33766965745357
1 5.36644047293616
1 5.52122597723003
1 5.56570565964821
1 5.60712009690023
1 5.66300423208743
1 5.66514259686913
1 5.67534726927919
1 5.81240592380042
1 5.92522478062696
1 5.93381941413441
1 5.98427109770311
1 5.98565402583205
1 6.05515692299313
1 6.05809430218476
1 6.09131101441445
1 6.11965752158963
1 6.13042419196115
1 6.28887153147068
1 6.32977252857695
1 6.33808014284925
1 6.45676918355347
1 6.48502196897216
1 6.59035226484124
1 6.59884332318236
1 6.60336173876099
1 6.67009552407771
1 6.73110910942222
1 6.75296641706414
1 6.77094593491614
1 6.95828178345678
1 6.99917574058471
1 7.18124875343567
1 7.2160622220336
1 7.25184300053345
1 7.27072859615507
1 7.53978854529375
1 7.62683747307804
1 8.30937998979063
1 8.83438781965087
1 9.22480466629532
1 10.6774780199582
1 11.2782346683741
1 11.3395674314469
1 11.8331754433414
1 13.3372479331164
1 13.3668568887691
1 14.4998735338549
1 15.4828226776902
1 15.6170772950205
1 16.0267888201666
};
\addplot [
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=+,
mark options={solid,draw=red},
forget plot
]
table{
2 3.41321096568804
2 3.42441728383389
2 3.47006454701832
2 3.5083260493326
2 3.50993022181865
2 3.5224280440296
2 3.53097156483447
2 3.53199517316025
2 3.53271118180697
2 3.54044801269578
2 3.57635424914675
2 3.5896987787456
2 3.64453768214226
2 3.65919183094817
2 3.66146964549055
2 3.67456647665076
2 3.7169973585756
2 3.73419637021325
2 3.73904009252507
2 3.77120490977482
2 3.77272560202542
2 3.77497681063978
2 3.79225323954729
2 3.79298102605436
2 3.80760997040253
2 3.81147340948309
2 3.81908053833612
2 3.96875014304215
2 3.99485534417404
2 4.01731506252257
2 4.06765568544008
2 4.0873257520362
2 4.11331236080408
2 4.13325633569113
2 4.26661484034241
2 4.36772600865394
2 4.40303481390946
2 4.40607151364257
2 4.46600165504838
2 4.47111977439536
2 4.49622909097077
2 4.53094088464027
2 4.54231297219618
2 4.57118373068546
2 4.6446735402234
2 4.6647201051236
2 4.71154608850202
2 4.80403096612948
2 4.82138190204484
2 4.96852570578322
2 5.07419215874747
2 5.08033573542001
2 5.10684604665064
2 5.14377910249464
2 5.17463377309759
2 5.17667049399468
2 5.36212407214132
2 5.40448313210525
2 5.41350356223682
2 5.41626341824251
2 5.41817161403
2 5.53622130790774
2 5.61664680822599
2 5.71410241240439
2 5.73419059729061
2 5.76038943550156
2 5.81282928328695
2 5.85167879792264
2 5.88710771337601
2 5.95097380392967
2 5.99247085551671
2 6.01852287751298
2 6.12793948220513
2 6.13691798442411
2 6.1524157717636
2 6.15824150074784
2 6.18114223490642
2 6.21273886630019
2 6.31339722911058
2 6.34381711049789
2 6.52578119369999
2 6.59982567229256
2 6.62614371942598
2 6.89054180919679
2 6.90561121762275
2 6.9983257531296
2 7.00336367711781
2 7.24601684774342
2 7.46677804595626
2 7.474430435742
2 7.5054467862249
2 7.74350903028379
2 7.87327847780469
2 8.01233531618229
2 8.02823255086298
2 8.27567062753628
2 8.57461049625301
2 8.74788905030809
2 8.93719593956683
2 9.30958954675193
2 9.94300146504975
2 9.98413037495241
2 11.0057097811966
2 11.084099718654
2 11.7427852334254
2 12.4827210667149
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do use `matlab2tikz` - just not for surf plots. I tried and the script is fine, but pdflatex can't handle the files. They are too big :( That's why I switched to pdf exports.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's been problem for me too. And doubly so because matlab does not export the correct size pdf for me (always find part of the plot hanging over the edge of the page). I have to do it by trial and error. Does this happen for you too?

Comment: Yes, sounds like it. I'm thinking about just leaving the axes completely blank right now. There is a nice scipt `plot2svg´, which I have used before. I used that to export my Matlab figures and then converted them to pdf with inkscape. But for surf plots, it's virtually impossible to fit those into some axis by pgfplots...