# Addplot3 with graphics / Image Offset to Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, 3d

I'm currently working with tikz and pgfplots to set a few plots. It works marvelously for a lot of applications, add I have set a number of plots (especially surfaces from matlab) with help of the scripts from [3-dimensional histogram in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52987/3-dimensional-histogram-in-pgfplots).

However, the current plot is over my head. The final result is offset to the axis somehow, but the mapping seems to do fine. I have scoured over several posts like [Why do I fail to import external 3D plots with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66245/why-do-i-fail-to-import-external-3d-plots-with-pgfplots), [Problem with external graphics and 3D pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78855/problem-with-external-graphics-and-3d-pgfplots) and a few others with no avail.

I added 4 corner points at the limits of the axis to be able to produce the necessary 4 points. those are the black crosses visible in the image.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% defining custom colors
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={-173}{18},
scale only axis,
clip = false,
xmin=-26.9710631775209,
xmax=-13.4358218716748,
ymin=0.106301614157972,
ymax=14.7011505583562,
z dir=reverse,
zmin=450.566465947184,
zmax=457.647656398296,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left
]
\addplot3 graphics[debug = visual,
points={% important
(-26.9711,0.1063,450.5665) => (337.0523,431.7509)
(-13.4358,14.7012,457.6477) => (138.9328,163.2305)
(-26.9711,14.7012,457.6477) => (391.2548,186.9052)
(-13.4358,0.1063,457.6477) => (86.5994,289.703)
}] {img};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: MWEimg]

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! Unfortunately, the web platform has rescaled your graphics such that the browser's "save graphics as" does not longer fit to your coordinates. Could you provide the graphics somewhere else? Dropbox or something like that?

Comment: Actually, I just managed to solve the problem. For some reason, my matlab figure window was in "Docked" mode. THis screws with the 
   get(gcf,'Position')
as it then always returns [1 1 w h], which then of course again screws with the pt calculation.

Using
    **set(gcf,'WindowStyle','normal')**
fixes that again!

Comment: If you still want the image, I'll upload it somewhere

Comment: Unrelated to the question: What is that surface? A DEM of a valley?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, my matlab figure window was in "Docked" mode. This screws with the

```
get(gcf,'Position')
```

as it then always returns `[1 1 w h]`, which then of course again screws with the pt calculation. Using

```
set(gcf,'WindowStyle','normal')
```

fixes that again!